# Rooted tree - Representation & Performance

Tags: c, data-structures, trees

## Representation 1 - Multi walk tree

```
typedef struct multiWalkTreeNode{
  struct multiWalkTreeNode * parent;
  void *item;
  struct multiWalkTreeNode **childPointer;
}Node;

typedef struct multiWalkTree{
  Node *root;
  int size; /*Number of nodes in the tree*/
}Tree;
```

Pictorial view:

### [image]

## Representation 2 - LCRS tree

```
typedef struct SiblingTreeNode{
  struct SiblingTreeNode *parent;
  void *item;
  struct SiblingTreeNode *firstChild;
  struct SiblingTreeNode *nextSibling;
}Node;

typedef struct LCRSTree{
  Node *root;
  int size;
}Tree;
```

Pictorial view:

### [image]

## Representation 3 - Tree using list(How to name this tree?)

```
typedef struct DListNode{
  int item;
  struct DListNode *next;
  struct DListNode *prev;
}DListNode;

typedef struct DList{ //Circular
  DListNode *head;
  int size;
}List;


typedef struct treeNode{
  struct treeNode *parent;
  void * item;
  List *childList;
  /* Sentinel node is created on initial construction of a "List" */
}Node;

typedef struct treeUsingList{
  Node *root;
  int size;
}Tree;
```

Pictorial view:
[image]

---

Parent pointer is introduced to perform DFS without recursion or explicit stack.

Please confirm the correctness of representation.

Question:

1) Do we have any name for tree in **Representation 3**?

2) For insert/delete/find operations, which representation performs better?

3) Are there any other representations for rooted tree, that can enhance performance?

Comment: Where did you get this code from?  Can you tell us if you know that this data structure actually has a well-known name and you just don't know what it is, or that you have no idea if it's even a well-known data structure?

Comment: @RobertHarvey From no where. I wrote it.  What are you trying to verify?

Comment: Is it your own design?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't know, what design mean? in just representing the data structure? Are you talking about **Representation 3**? My teacher in cs 61B hinted that, one can use list instead of sibling nodes. So, I wrote corrsponding code but I do not know the name of **Representation 3**.

Comment: What makes you think it has a well-known name?  If you and your teacher  designed and wrote it, why would we know more about it than you?

Comment: Let me rephrase my first question

Comment: You changed the words, but not the meaning.  You're essentially asking "What is the name of this data structure my teacher and I invented?"  Um, the name you gave it?

Comment: SO basically you show us your teacher design and ask to do the work of evaluating if they're good or bad ? Questions are supposed to show that you have search yourself for those, I don't see any of your own search about insert/delete/find neither about performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some considerations:

1. In #1, you aren't capturing a size of the `childPointer` array, so you cannot know how many children there are.
2. Your code for #3 uses `void *item` in the text, but `Node *item` in the diagram.  Further, the items labeled sentinel have (struckthru) item, next and prev, but should (to match the text) have head and size .
3. None of these data structures are optimized for find operations, so among these, the fewer data structures the better, within a small margin (as none is great for find).  If find is the primary concern I'd move to a totally different data structure (e.g. B-Tree or balanced binary tree, or anything else)!
4. The #3 choice, I see as basically broken.  It uses a doubly linked list, which at first blush might imply some improvement for large numbers of children regarding insert/delete.  However, observe that the parent pointers from the nodes only refer to other tree nodes, and not also to the position in the doubly linked list (which themselves do not offer a parent pointer).  So a full traversal of immediate children is still necessary, just like in option #2, and, the doubly linked list offers no improvement, just more maintenance required and space taken (all bad).
5. Workload is going to be the primary concern here regarding which is best for performance.  Regular trees (not one of your options) would be the best for insertion if there are, say, two or fewer children.  For huge numbers of children, a doubly linked list might be better, but not if implemented as #3.

Comment: For your point #4 and #5, In representation #3,  Are you saying that parent in `treeNode` should point to `DListNode`? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: #3 is using a doubly linked list but not taking any advantage of it relative to a singly linked list.  Try writing the delete operation, for example, for #2 and for #3 (as it is), it will come out almost the same, with a search from the start for the node in the list.  The advantage of the doubly linked list is not having to search backward for immediate predecessor.  But if you're searching from the start anyway, you know the immediate predecessor, so doubly linked is no additional help over singly linked.  (An alteration to #3 would be able to eliminate the search-for-node-from-start.)

Comment: **1)  did not get this point *parent pointers from the nodes only refer to other tree nodes, and not also to the position in the doubly linked list* My understanding is, parent pointers of `treeNode` should point to other `treeNode`.  **2) I did not get this point *For huge numbers of children, a doubly linked list might be better, but not if implemented as #3.*

Comment: What that means is you cannot reach the doubly linked list elements given the tree node without a search of the parent's child linked list nodes.

Comment: In rep#3, How would you reach child `treeNode`'s without traversing linked list?

Comment: Ok, let's start with the API for the delete operation.  This important because that will tell us what information we have when we're trying to delete.  Any information not provided by the operation that is needed internally to maintain the data structure after the actual deletion but during the delete operation's cleanup will have to be found by looking at the data structure itself.  So, can we presume that delete looks something like `void delete ( treeNode *node );`?  (or maybe `void delete ( treeUsingList list, treeNode *node );`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50055/discussion-between-overexchange-and-erik-eidt).

Answer (score 0):

You can regard the representation 3 as a binary tree which is just arranged differently. So instead of going down you order the element on the same level. You can also call it a graph, since you have back-pointers.

Generally a hash can improve things tremendously. Since you did not state for what purpose you want better performance it's hard to give any statement.